# Looping array with preg_match

Tags: php

I'm trying to loop though a multidimensional array looking for matches(preg_match()). Errors I'm getting are both uninitialized string offset and empty regular expression. I don't think I'm looping the array correctly.

The array contains data from the database where I storage the ID of the type, the string to match and the type name that needs to be assigned if matching.

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "1" 
        [1]=> string(7) "/call/i" 
        [2]=> string(14) "Telephone call" } 
    [1]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "2" 
        [1]=> string(10) "/contact/i" 
        [2]=> string(7) "Contact" } 
    [2]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "3" 
        [1]=> string(10) "/meeting/i" 
        [2]=> string(7) "Meeting" } 
        }
```

```
$filterQuery = "SELECT ID, matchstring, type FROM rulesdes";
            $results = mysqli_query($this->connection, $filterQuery);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
                $array[] = $row;
            }

foreach ($array as $value){
                foreach ($value as $types){
                    if (preg_match($types[1], $subject)){
                        $emailType = $array[1];
                    } else {
                        $emailType = "All emails";
                    }
                    $queryType = "INSERT INTO rules (ID, Type) VALUES ('$id', '$emailType')";
                    mysqli_query($this->connection, $queryType);
                }
            }
```

Once matched it saves the name of the type and sends it to the database with the unique id.

Tried AbraCadaver's solution (not worked):

```
            $filterQuery = "SELECT ID, matchstring, type FROM rulesdes";
            $results = mysqli_query($this->connection, $filterQuery);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
                $array[] = $row;
            }
            foreach ($array as $values){
                if (strpos($subject, $values[1])){
                    $emailType = $values[2];
                } else {
                    $emailType = "All emails";
                }
                $queryType = "INSERT INTO rules (ID, Type) VALUES ('$id', '$emailType')";
                mysqli_query($this->connection, $queryType);
            }
```

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: Sorry AbraCadaver, been out the office for a few days. I've replied to you on your answer! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You only need one loop and then access the array elements in each array:

```
foreach ($array as $values){
    $id = $values[0];

    if (preg_match($values[1], $subject)){
        $emailType = $values[2];
    } else {
        $emailType = "All emails";
    }
    $queryType = "INSERT INTO rules (ID, Type) VALUES ('$id', '$emailType')";
    mysqli_query($this->connection, $queryType);
}
```

However, it would be easier and faster to store `call`, `contact` and `meeting` and use `strpos`:

```
    if (strpos($subject, $values[1]) !== false){
        $emailType = $values[2];
    } else {
        $emailType = "All emails";
    }
```

Comment: Hey AbraCadaver!
Unfortunately hasn't fixed my issue. I've tried storaging call, contact and meeting as you mentioned and doesn't seem to fix my issue. It sends all emails to "All Emails"
Not sure if I'm doing anything wrong. This code is inside a foreach loop which goes though all emails. I've attached the code I used to the question.

Comment: His solutions should work. Can we have an example of `$subject`?

Comment: @iArcadia an example could be "Contact form", "Meeting information" or "Hello". This last one will go to "All emails". 
I have attached the code I have after editing... Please review it just to check I have done everything correctly. Thank you!